# Where does a Django generic view class call the database?

Tags: django

I can inherit from a class based generic view from `generic.ListView` as in

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
```

Supposedly the `.as_view()` function gets called when the Django app starts up to create an instance of this view.

I find the definition of `get_queryset` in `MultipleObjectMixin` but what I dont find is, from where is this method called from?

Comment: It's called in the `get` method of `BaseListView` https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/list.py#L142. Note though, this does not execute a DB query, the queryset is executed when you iterate over it or call certain methods on it

Comment: Thank you. And where does `get` get called from? Or speaking more generally, what is a good way to investigate this?

Comment: Maybe to elaborate on my question, I come from a Spring background where beans are managed by a Spring container. Is there a similar concept in Django?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, sorry I can't say. The dispatch method of the base CBV (the dispatch method is the entrypoint to all CBVs) calls a method on the view that is the request method lowercase, GET requests will trigger the get method, POST requests will trigger the post method and so on https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py#L93. Not sure how much help it will be but I find this website to be helpful when exploring the available options of the built-in views https://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: @TMOTTM, see [detailed descriptions](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/), with full methods and attributes, for each of Django's class-based generic views.